# Can Pivot Table perform operations comparing two field?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a table that has two category columns, a column for number started and a column for number finished.  I'd like to roll up by one category column and calculate a percentage finished in a pivot table (rather than array formulae).

Imagine my data looks like this:

```
Date - School - Starters - Finishers
7/1    USC      100        25
7/1    UCLA     200        50
7/2    USC      250        100
7/2    UCLA     200        100
```

I want my pivot table to look like this

```
Date - Finish rate
7/1    25%
7/2    44%
```

But when I go into Value Field Settings to switch to a calculation, I can't figure how to get the column comparison to happen.

Comment: Hey pnuts, that's what I thought too, but no this is a different case.  In that question the user wants to know the proportion total for the category assigned to a specific value.  Here I want to compare two different fields for the same value.

Comment: Thanks pnuts, nailed it.  I just couldn't find "Calculated Field"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a calculated field that compares two other fields in the "Pivottable Tools" "Analyze" ribbon "Fields, Items, & Sets" button - "Calculated Field".  Just build comparison expression in the "Formula" text field of the "Insert Calculated Field" dialogue box.